# Convert PNG image to grayscale without losing transparency using Delphi

Tags: delphi, png, delphi-10.3-rio, alpha-transparency

I want to convert a PNG image to grayscale with transparency (not losing alpha channel). Probably using `TBitmap` and `TPngImage` components or Skia4Delphi.

From [image: transparent colored PNG] to [image: transparent gaeyscale PNG]

But how? I'm using Delphi 10.3.3 VCL.

Comment: I think you should give skia4delphi a try. It is an open Source Framework and has tons of features for manipulating images. See here for some Samples: https://github.com/skia4delphi/skia4delphi/tree/main/Samples

Comment: @fisi-pjm Skia4Delphi looks awesome. However sample code of what I want to do isn't there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Skia4Delphi library:

```
uses
  System.UITypes, Skia;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  LImage: ISkImage;
  LSurface: ISkSurface;
  LPaint: ISkPaint;
begin
  LImage := TSkImage.MakeFromEncodedFile('..\..\delphi.png');
  LPaint := TSkPaint.Create;
  LPaint.ColorFilter := TSkColorFilter.MakeHighContrast(TSkHighContrastConfig.Create(True, TSkContrastInvertStyle.NoInvert, 0));
  LSurface := TSkSurface.MakeRaster(LImage.Width, LImage.Height);
  LSurface.Canvas.Clear(TAlphaColors.Null);
  LSurface.Canvas.DrawImage(LImage, 0, 0, LPaint);
  LSurface.MakeImageSnapshot.EncodeToFile('..\..\delphi-grayscale.png');
end;
```